# Selecting records assuming future dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, select

I used the following *select statement* to select sum of amount assuming no future dates. How do I change this statement to include future dates?

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as allPreviousAmount 
FROM `fn_table`
WHERE MONTH(transdate) < ? OR YEAR(transdate) < 2019 )
```

The **?** is representing the month number. I have data in 2018, 2019 and 2020. Now I want to select all data before February 2019. How do I select it? The problem is that this also select data in 2020.

Comment: how about YEAR > YEAR (CURRENT_DATE())?

Comment: @RakeshShewale, how about previous dates? I said assuming future dates but keeping previous dates

Comment: if I understand correctly, you need the result for both previous dates and future dates (including current date, i guess). Then why not to remove the WHERE clause for dates?

Comment: if you also include a sample table records and the expected output. It might help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regards your existing query, surely you'd need AND, not OR, to ensure no future dates? Say it's July 2020 and you have a date of January 2021 which is in the future. If you say `MONTH('jan-2021') < MONTH('jul-2020') OR YEAR('jan-2021') < YEAR('jul-2020')` then this will be true because jan is earlier than jul so a future date of January 2021 will be returned

Not really sure why you didn't just `WHERE transdate < CURRENT_DATE()` unless a any day this month is also classed as a future date... (by demanding the the month and the year have to be less than the current date, if it's 13th July 2020 you'll only get records up to end of June 2020 if you consider month and year only)

But to include all dates past and future simply remove the WHERE clause entirely

---

Edit in response to comment:

If you want a query that gives "all data up to but not including 01 Jul 2005" then do:

```
WHERE transdate < ?
```

And in your front end supply a date type parameter of 01-jul-2005. Any date can be supplied, but to cut off at a particular month end, supply a date that is the first day of some month

You can reuse the same query for future dates too by providing a date higher than any possible date in the table, such as 01-jan-3000

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my misunderstanding. What I want though is to select all previous dates from my specified month and year. Suppose I want to select all previous month record, given February 2019 in my where clause. I also have data in 2020.

Comment: I think my edit to my answer covers all the question already. The answer also explains why you were getting data after feb 2019 - because you used OR not AND

Comment: I don't understand why `SELECT SUM(amount) AS allPreviousAmount 
FROM fn_table
WHERE MONTH(transdate)<2 AND YEAR(transdate) < 2019` is not selecting any data at all and is returning null

Comment: My transdate data type is also datetime data type. Will it cause some error if I use `DATE_FORMAT(transdate,'%Y-%m-%d')<2019-02-01`?

Comment: I'd need to see the table data to answer the first question, and no you don't (and shouldn't) use date format to change a date to a string and then compare it to a number generated by the sum `2019-02-01` - 2019 minus 2 minus 1 is 2016. Mysql might promote the number 2016 to a string and then return all dates 2015 and before but honestly you're making this way harder than it needs to be- just use a single parameter ? Into which you put a date of 1st feb 2019 and let mysql do the rest. You'll get all data up to 31-jan2019 23:59:59.9999999999999 but not the first of feb

Comment: Dates and datetimes are conceptually the same thing; a date just has a time of midnight. You don't need to go to any efforts to cut the time portion off before you compare just like you don't need to cut the decimal portion of 9.72537 off before you ask if it is `< 10`:  `9.72357 < 10` **is every bit as true as** `CAST(9.72537 as INTEGER) < 10`

Comment: what about this `DATE_FORMAT(transdate,'%Y-%m-%d')<'2019-02-01'`? my fn_table is like `id, amount, transdate`

Comment: Realistically, if `SELECT SUM(amount) AS allPreviousAmount FROM fn_table WHERE MONTH(transdate)<2 AND YEAR(transdate) < 2019` returns **one row containing a single value of null** then all the `amount`s of all the records before feb 2019, are null or non-numeric. If it returns **no rows at all**, there are no rows with a date before feb 2019. All this is dependent on it being true that transdate really is a date column and not a varchar that looks like a date. If transdate is a string, anything could happen when the db guesses what date it might be before passingit to the YEAR/MONTH functions

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I really appreciate it. My final select statement is now `SELECT SUM(amount) AS allPreviousAmount FROM fn_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(transdate,'%Y-%m-%d')<'2019-02-01'` Could this statement be reliable? This selects all records before February 2019. Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Argh. No. This statement will convert the date to a string and compare the string. It will work but it's a shitty way to do it because it's slow, the db will spend its life converting data needlessly and it means any index on the column cannot be used. Please just use `WHERE transdate < ?` and provide a date to the ? parameter.. if you're looking for something that will work in your query tool, write `WHERE transdate < '2019-02-01'` and mysql will convert your string `2019-02-01` to a date and then use the date to lookup, but for your front end app use the parameterized form I gave

Comment: You need to be really clear about the difference between `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(transdate,'%Y-%m-%d')<'2019-02-01'` and `WHERE transdate<'2019-02-01'`. On a table of ten million rows, *evey time the query runs* the first way will turn every one of the ten million dates into ten million strings (slow), compare the strings (slow) and can't be indexed (slow). The second way will turn one string into a date(fast), compare ten million dates(internally dates are numeric; faster than string compare) and can be indexed(fast). Never convert all of a table data, always match parameters to table datatype